# El significado de “a sus afines”

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Según RAE, “[afín](https://dle.rae.es/af%C3%ADn)” significa

1. adj. Próximo, contiguo. Campos afines.
2. adj. Parecido, similar.
3. m. y f. Pariente por afinidad.

¿Entonces qué definición debo elegir para poder entender el siguiente [subtítulo](https://www.publico.es/politica/trama-kitchen-cospedal-aspirante-liderar-pp-cedio-votos-casado-primarias.html/amp)? ¡Muchas gracias!

“El actual líder del PP saldó su deuda con Cospedal colocándola dentro del Comité Ejecutivo del PP y premiando con cargos de relevancia a sus afines. Fuentes de la dirección creen que el día escogido para anunciar su imputación no es casual.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Más abajo en el artículo se dan ejemplos de la gente que fue premiada con esos cargos de relevancia:

> premiando con cargos de relevancia a sus afines, como **Dolors Montserrat**, actual portavoz del PP en el Parlamento Europeo o **Vicente Tirado**, al que Casado situó en su núcleo duro.

Ninguno de los dos es pariente de Cospedal (que yo sepa), por lo que entiendo que el uso de "sus afines" es una [sustantivación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivaci%C3%B3n) de la primera acepción ("próximo, contiguo") y se refiere a "sus *personas* afines", es decir, sus personas cercanas o de confianza.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!